# sprite animation: function not recognized and semi-colon expected in for-loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, sprite

I am working on a sprite animation project. On mouse over, the console log  reports the function is undefined. Additionally VS code is reporting an error that a semi-colon is expected just within the last parenthesis of my for loop.

I have tried adding semi colons within the for-loop (even though this make no sense to me), and double checking all my parenthesis and curly-brackets.

HTML:

```
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#catimage{
height: 256px;
width: 512px;
background: 
url('https://docs.coronalabs.com/images/simulator/sprites-cat- 
running.png')
}
```

full JS:

```
var tID;

function catimate() {

    // start position for the image slicer
    var position = 512;
    // 150 ms of interval for setInterval()
    const interval = 150;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var catPosition =
    [[0, 0],
        [512, 0],
        [1024, 0],
        [1536, 0],
        [0, 256],
        [512, 256],
        [1024, 256],
        [1536, 256]];

     tID = setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundPosition = 
       `${x}px ${y}px`;

        for (i = 0, i < catPosition.length, i++) {
            var x = catPosition[i][0];
            var y = catPosition[i][1];
            console.log(x, y);
        }
    }
    , interval);
}
```

Eventually I hope to animate this cat through one loop. However, at this point, I am just trying to get my function called, and then see the values from my catPosition Array to be console logged during a mouse over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to make the for loop work you need to use semi colons instead of commas on line 24 to look like this `for (i = 0; i < catPosition.length; i++) {`

What you could do to achieve the effect you want is to set x and y inside the setInterval and and update i instead of going through a for loop each time else the cat will just be stuck in one place.

So it might look something like this:

```js
var tID;

function catimate() {

    // start position for the image slicer
    var position = 512;
    // 150 ms of interval for setInterval()
    const interval = 150;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var catPosition =
    [[0, 0],
        [512, 0],
        [1024, 0],
        [1536, 0],
        [0, 256],
        [512, 256],
        [1024, 256],
        [1536, 256]];

     tID = setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundPosition = `${x}px ${y}px`;

        x = catPosition[i][0];
        y = catPosition[i][1];
        console.log(x, y);

        i++;
    }
    , interval);
}

catimate()
```

this should make the cat move just one position for every call of the interval.